# Dual Power Source for single output?

Tags: redundancy

In the world of USB, there's a type of cable with dual male head for 1 single female head, like this in below picture, while 1 head is for data+power and the other for power only.

I have tested it could bring power to device with any 1 of the head (and without power loss when I unplug anyone of them)

However, I do not find anything similar in 110/220v AC supply and all it suggested is by using Automatic Transfer Switch.

Is it technically possible to have something similar in the AC world, making single-powered device having redundancy without ATS / UPS?

Thanks everyone!

[image]

Comment: This is a very bad idea for a number of reasons I'm too sleepy to go into at the moment. The double USB thing is also a bad idea, and not actually allowed by the USB spec.

Comment: There is no connection between USB and AC power. The further apart these two remain the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a thing does not exist. No one would ever want to make or use such a cable because it will be dangerous for many reasons.

First of all plugging only one plug to wall would leave the live parts of the second plug exposed for touching.

If plugged to two different circuits, it will also be dangerous as it will connect the circuits together, which is something that should not be done.

Some countries have unpolarized plugs so there is a 50% chanse you will plug it the wrog way and blow up fuses.

If connected to outlets that are on a different mains phase (two phase or three phase household electricity) it will short out the two phases and blow the fuse.

If redundancy is required, a device such as a redundant power supply will have two separate mains inlets.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Just wonder that USB-dual-head stuff is also exposing the same threats, but just because
1. USB is low voltage
2. USB connector are inside (i.e. no exposed plug)
3. no unpolarized plugs

so it remains in the market? or because it is DC, not AC so it works?

Comment: No, it works by pure luck. If you have a computer which has one USB which provides standby supply and another USB with main 5V supply, the improper cable can destroy the computer by shorting the standby and main supplies. There might be fuses or protection but devices don't expect this kind of cable so they may not survive it. What if you plugged it into two different computers or a powebank? Will it blow up? 1) it is the isolation from mains 2) no, again it is the isolation so even with exposed pins it would be safe, 3) yes you can't connect it wrong 4) DC or AC has nothing to do with it.